# Какие существуют способы хранения файлов в sql базах данных?

Tags: sql, файлы, файловая-система

Как лучше хранить файлы в sql базе данных? Хранить сами файлы(картинки, текстовые файлы, аудио файлы) или хранить в базе сслыку на эти файлы в системе? Каким способом лучше реализовать тот или иной способ?

Comment: Зависит от конкретной СУБД. Например, в Sql Server есть и третий способ: [FILESTREAM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) - сочетает в себе преимущества обоих.

Comment: скорее всего лусше ссылку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давай попробую ответить.

Смысл хранить данные в базе имеется только если с ними работать на прямую.

Например: у вас есть модуль/функция который который может найти, определить, сгруппировать файлы по содержимому по типу плагият или нет. Или какой нибудь по типу google картинок который находит схожие изображения. Короче говоря вы будите использовать содержимое.

Если нет то есть смысл хранить только ссылки, поскольку разрастание базы не ведёт к улучшению производительности. Сохранение и считывание таких данных будет отнимать всегда лишнее время, когда как ссылки могут спокойно существовать и без самих файлов, при обращении к которым будет вежливо указывается идти лесом.

Answer (score 3):

Не касаясь вопроса *а_на_фига_это_вообще_надо* отвечу на прямой вопрос:

> Какие существуют способы хранения файлов в sql базах данных?

За все способы не скажу, но я лично использовал такой способ:

1. Заголовочная таблица с метаданными файла, поля типа:

- Идентификатор файла
- Название файла
- mime тип файла
- размер файла
- timestamp'ы `lastmodified/created`
- checksum файла
- список тегов

2. Ссылка 1 ко многим на таблицу с контентом файла с полями

- Первичный ключ
- Идентификатор файла
- порядковый номер куска/chunk'а
- BLOB поле

Обращаю внимание, что поле `BLOB` является стандартным типом поддерживаемым практически любой SQL СУБД.

Работает это так:

1. Берем файл
2. Определяем его метаданные и пишем в заголовочную таблицу
3. Открываем файл делим его на куски и куски пишем в список `BLOB` полей

P.S. Для любителей говорить о том, что типа страдает скорость приведу маленькую справочку - файл в файловой системе любой ОС организован как БД. То есть заголовочек и есть списочек контента файла на которые хранятся ссылки

Comment: порядок кусков еще?

Comment: Конечно, порядок тоже нужен

Comment: Да если данные нужны в базе данных то храните в блоб. Если нет то чем плох вариант не хранить их вовсе?

Answer (score 2):

Для больших файлов лучше хранить ссылку.

Для самих файлов можно использовать s3 (ceph, minio) кластер, для масштабируемости/надежности.

Answer (score 2):

Что ж за ответы такие однобокие?
Хотя, вопрос так составлен. Без уточнения конкретной СУБД и без уточнения, что именно будет делаться с хранимыми данными.

Кроме двух упомянутых способов - хранение ссылки или самих данных в БД - есть и другие.
Например, в Sql Server есть [FILESTREAM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) - он сочетает в себе преимущества обоих: хранит данные в файловой системе, обеспечивает транзакционную согласованность и быструю передачу.

---

[To BLOB or Not To BLOB: Large Object Storage in a Database or a Filesystem](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/to-blob-or-not-to-blob-large-object-storage-in-a-database-or-a-filesystem/) - Рекомендую к ознакомлению данный документ (кликните View Publication, чтобы скачать pdf).

Кратко: мелкие файлы (до 256 кб) лучше хранить в БД в виде блобов, большие (более 1 Мб) - в файловой системе.
Конечно, нюансов много. Зависит как от СУБД, так и от файловой системы.
Корень всех зол - фрагментация!