# Как сохранять файлы в бд ms sql server и потом их доставать оттуда?

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt5

В c++, ms sql и qt я недавно. Пишу сейчас функциональную прогу на фреймворке qt. Суть вопроса в том, что надо каким-то образом сохранять файлы в бд ms sql server и потом их доставать оттуда. Как это сделать?

Comment: есть тип данных blob, но вообще СУБД на это не особо рассчитаны. лучше сохранять файлы локально, а в БД хранить только ссылки

Comment: В ms sql есть такая штука как filestream, который это и делает. А зранить надо именно в бд, что бы не писать еще и клиент-серверное приложение

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1165760/184217

Comment: [Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/binary-large-object-blob-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) - официальная документация (язык переключается в левом нижнем углу). Почитайте там сравнение разных способов. В меню слева выбор разделов.