# Как хранить файлы в БД?

Tags: база-данных, sqlite3, aiogram-3.x

Я делаю тг бота и одна из его функций связана с хранением аудио файлов. Как лучше это сделать, можете мне пожалуйста обьяснить на простом языке как можно это сделать? Мб можно ваще не хранить в бд файлы, а как то по другому сделать? Сейчас бд - sqlite 3, мб в ней можно хранить.

Comment: Лучше файлы положить в папку, а в бд хранить путь до файла

Comment: Храните в БД пути к файлам от того каталога, где у вас эти файлы хранятся. `sqlite` довольно хилая БД, лучше там файлы не хранить.

Comment: Мелкие файлы лучше хранить в прямо в БД, большие - в файловой системе, а ссылки на них в БД. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1165760/184217

Comment: Можно ли файлы хранить в SQLite? Нужно! [35% Faster Than The Filesystem](https://www.sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html), [SQLite As An Application File Format](https://www.sqlite.org/appfileformat.html)

Comment: [Internal Versus External BLOBs in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html) - подберите правильный размер страницы. / Вообще, в документации SQLite по ссылкам много полезной информации. Если эту СУБД правильно настроить, то она в клочья рвёт все остальные СУБД во многих сценариях (не во всех, конечно). Разве что при записи из многих клиентов (процессов/потоков) она тормозит.